# How remap keyboard on "asciitilde layout mode"

Tags: keyboard, xmodmap, remapping

I'm trying currently to use the `xmodmap -e` function in order to remap my keyboard. I want to replace the `twosuperior` key with `greater` and `less` depend of the asciitilde mode being activated.

*I talk about `asciitilde` or `grave` mode in reference to [this convention](https://gist.github.com/repent/d13927574cfc72784082)*

I wonder how remap the "asciitilde mode layout" since I retrieve the same keycode for the "grave mode layout" and "asciitilde mode layout".

Here what I retrieve with the `xev` process :

```
// retrieving less
keycode 94 (keysym 0x3c, less)"<" 

// passing in asciitilde layout mode
keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L),

// retrieving greater with asciitilde mode activated
keycode 94 (keysym 0x3e, greater)">"

 ------------------

// retrieving the code of twosuperior key 
keycode 49 (keysym 0xb2, twosuperior) "²"


// passing in asciitilde layout mode activated
keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L)

// retrieving the code of twosuperior key with asciitilde being activated  
keycode 49 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol)
```

As you can see I retrieve the same keycode for *grave layout mode* and *asciitilde layout mode*.

How can I make change on *asciitilde layout key map* ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In fact it is very simple.

The first argument refer to the "lowercase mode layout" and the second argument to the "uppercase mode layout", so the code syntax is the following :

```
xmodmap -e "keycode [keycode_number] = grave_mode_argument asciitilde_mode_argument"
```

So in our case, to put the `less` and `greater` symbols in the place of `twosuperior` symbol, we can just run the following code :

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 49 = less greater"
```

Also, we can retrieve your keycodes numbers using the `[xev process][1]`.